# Codeigniter URL not working without index.php

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I've just set up a new webiste http://www.reviewongadgets.com

But there is a problem with URL rendering

When I put an URL as below it's not working and gives page not found error
http://www.reviewongadgets.com/latest-mobile

But it works with
http://www.reviewongadgets.com/index.php/latest-mobile

I don't want to show index.php in my URL, it should be http://www.reviewongadgets.com/latest-mobile
, can you please suggest me what should I do ?

This is my `.htaccess` file contents:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Config file contents:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.reviewongadgets.com";
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Same type configuration working for my another website

Changed my `.htaccess` content to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You should share your solution with others so when they come look at this question they get the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common solution to this problem is usually the missing question mark `?` after index.php in `.htaccess`, so

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

should be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

E.G. on my Windows XAMPP, I do not need the "?", but in a Linux hosting environment it is usually required.

Answer (score 5):

i aggree with Vlakarados, but i will share my .htaccess setting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

its work perfectly.

i hope that's work to for your CI website

Answer (score 0):

You might not have `rewrite_module` module loaded.
Try running below command.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```