# CodeIgniter won't run in a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I have a CodeIgniter install running in our root web directory that I copied into a subdirectory called /dev... I edited the config/config.php file to reflect the change so it is now like this:

```
$config['base_url']  = 'http://mysite.com/dev';
$config['sbase_url']     = 'https://mysite.com/dev';
$config['default_email'] = 'noreply@mysite.com';
$config['site_url']  = 'http://mysite.com/dev';
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I hover over any links on the site they are correct, for example the contact us page link reads www.mysite.com/dev/contact but when I click any of the links I get a 404 error...

Is there something common I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465103/codeignitor-url-not-working-without-index-php/8521321#8521321

Comment: Did you put the .htaccess in the dev directory? Otherwise it won't work;)

Answer (score 3):

Enable `FollowSymlinks` & add a `./` in front of index.php in your RewriteRule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # block hidden directories
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Also, I would leave blank `$config['base_url'] = '';` & use the `base_url()` url helper when constructing links instead, which makes moving environments easier (*e.g. subdir'd dev & root-level production*).

... and of course, insure that ModRewrite is enabled in your Apache config.

Comment: That didn't help... the default controller shows up, i.e. www.mysite.com/dev resolves the index page but if you try to go to any other page like www.mysite.com/dev/about it 404's

Comment: Are you quite certain ModRewrite is enabled on your Apache server?

Comment: Well the root version of the site works fine, I have an .htaccess file there to remove the index.php from the URL and it works.

Comment: Try adding `RewriteBase /dev/` below `RewriteEngine On` to the .htaccess - I believe that should resolve it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked... I don't have access to the httpd.config file, is there a way i can test for mod_rewrite with php?

Comment: Yes, you can create an `info.php` somewhere which contains: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` - look at the _Loaded Modules_ section and see if it lists `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: This is a clients remote server BTW, I don;t usually have mod_rewrite issues on my server.

Comment: Once you get mod_rewrite module enabled properly on your clients server my answer should get you up & running.