# Removing index.php from Codeigniter URLs not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

This question has been answered a few times, but the answers are not working for me. I recently reinstalled Windows 10, so the XAMPP installation is a clean one, but it used to work in my last PC. **rewrite_module is enabled**.

When I go to `http://localhost`, my app redirects me to `http://localhost/login`, but it says 404 until I type `http://localhost/index.php/login`

My **config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In the **.htaccess** file of the codeigniter's root folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Solutions I tried:

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235941/removing-index-php-in-codeigniter-just-works-for-the-default-controller-url) (This gives me "Object not found!" error)

[Answer 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641333/codeigniter-remove-index-php-form-url)

[Answer 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465103/codeigniter-url-not-working-without-index-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the .htaccess file adding this line:

```
RewriteBase /YOURPROJECTFOLDER/
```

so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ShopCaseCodeigniter/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings in your apache server httpd.conf

```
AllowOverride All -> AllowOverride FileInfo
```